# Move existing category attribute into new group

Tags: category, install, setup

I basically want to move an existing category attribute into a newly created group in my setup file. This is the way I expected it to work:

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$entityTypeId = 'catalog_category';

$installer->addAttribute($entityTypeId, 'my_attribute', array(
'group'         => 'Adams Group',
'input'         => 'text',
'type'          => 'varchar',
'label'         => 'My Attribute Label',
'visible'       => 1,
'required'      => 0,
'user_defined' => 1,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE
));

$installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'meta_title', array(
'group' => 'Adams Group'
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

It adds the new attribute to the group as expected, but it doesn't move meta_title in the new group. I suppose I'm using the wrong code. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::updateAttributeGroup`. I don't know exactly how to use it that's why I don't write it as an answer.

Comment: I think that just updates attribute group data, whereas I want to update attribute data.

Comment: I think you might be right. Ignore me for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move an attribute of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category to a new group, through an installer script, by performing the following logic.

Prerequisites:

- The catalog attribute must already exist
- The group which you are moving the attribute TO must already exist

The only changes here that should be necessary, are the values of the top two variables ($attribute_code and $attribute_group_name).

```
<?php
/**
 * Moving a category attribute from one group to another.
 */

$this->startSetup();

$attribute_code       = 'your_attribute_code'; // Catalog Category attribute we want to move
$attribute_group_name = 'Some Group Name';     // Group we want to move it to (must already exist).

// Some necessary objects for this operation.
$conn  = $this->getConnection();
$read  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

// Fetch the id of the attribute we want to move
$attribute_id = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_category', $attribute_code)->getId();

// Fetch the 'entity_type_id' for a Magento category. 
$entity_type_id = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('catalog_category')->getId();

// Fetch the 'attribute_set_id' for Magento categories (unlike products, there's only one for categories)
$tbl = $conn->getTableName('eav_attribute_set');
$sql = "SELECT `attribute_set_id` FROM `{$tbl}` WHERE `entity_type_id` = :entity_type_id";
$bnd = array('entity_type_id' => $entity_type_id);

$attribute_set_id = $read->fetchCol($sql, $bnd);
$attribute_set_id = $attribute_set_id[0];

// Now we'll need the 'attribute_group_id' for the group we want to move the attribute TO
$tbl = $conn->getTableName('eav_attribute_group');
$sql = "SELECT `attribute_group_id` FROM `{$tbl}` WHERE `attribute_set_id` = :attribute_set_id AND `attribute_group_name` = :attribute_group_name";
$bnd = array('attribute_set_id' => $attribute_set_id, 'attribute_group_name' => $attribute_group_name);

$attribute_group_id = $read->fetchCol($sql, $bnd);
$attribute_group_id = $attribute_group_id[0];

// We now have all the information we need to move our attribute to the new group.
$tbl = $conn->getTableName('eav_entity_attribute');
$sql = "UPDATE `{$tbl}` SET `attribute_group_id` = :attribute_group_id WHERE `entity_type_id` = :entity_type_id AND `attribute_set_id` = :attribute_set_id AND `attribute_id` = :attribute_id";
$bnd = array('attribute_group_id' => $attribute_group_id, 'entity_type_id' => $entity_type_id, 'attribute_set_id' => $attribute_set_id, 'attribute_id' => $attribute_id);

$write->query($sql, $bnd);

$this->endSetup();
```

If we read this code carefully, one will see that all that really is happening here, is that we're finding the ID of the group, and updating the `attribute_group_id` column in the `eav_entity_attribute` table, for the record which contains our attribute. Personally, I find it easier to just do this directly in the database. However you asked how to do this via an installer script ;)

Answer (score 2):

From memory, I think it's something like -

```
$installer->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, array('group' => 'Adams Group'), 'meta_title');
```

Not tested it though sorry.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: This is used to add a product attribute to an attribute group.

Answer (score 1):

### Doing it the correct way

This is how you do it for product attributes, and it should work by changing the entity type id:

```
$setup = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
```

Load your attribute:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
    ->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'my_attribute');
```

Get attribute set ID (if you have multiple attribute sets, you'll have to do 
this for every attribute set):

```
$setId = $setup->getAttributeSetId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'Default');
```

Get attribute group ID (in this case I'm moving an attribute into the Visibility tab):

```
$groupId = $setup->getAttributeGroupId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $setId, 'Visibility');
```

And lastly, call `addAttributeToSet`:

```
$setup->addAttributeToSet(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $setId, $groupId, $attribute->getId());
```

Comment: Instantiating `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` via its class name directly is not the correct way

Comment: At least it's not through direct SQL, I guess which I was pointing at.. :P I'll change it to the `getModel` variant.

Comment: Perfect answer though :-)

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that this is not possible to do with an existing function through the setup file.

Comment: Actually it is, please see my answer.